# imellipse on Gui Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm doing this project on image processing. I'm trying to use imellipse to take the mask of the region that I want so that I can plot it on my Gui interface.

I always get the error "createMask expects a current figure containing an image"
Does anyone have an idea what causes this error?

This is my program

```
global RC
b = imellipse(handles.axes1)
position =wait(b)
ma = createMask(b,RC);
imk=immultiply(ma,RC);
axes=(handles.axes1);
figure;imshow(imk);
```

Comment: Why are you passing `RC` to the createMask function?  What is it defined to be?

Comment: RC is my pretreated image.

Answer (score 0):

The format for `createMask` is:

```
BW = createMask(h_roi,h_im);
```

Where `h_roi` is a handle (in your case `b`) to the roi, and `h_im` is a handle to the image.  e.g. in this standard example from the docs:

```
img = imread('pout.tif');
h_im = imshow(img); % creates image handle
e = imellipse(gca,[55 10 120 120]); % creates handle to roi
BW = createMask(e,h_im); % uses those two to get mask
```

If you don't have the handle to the image, you can fetch it from the appropriate axes with `findobj`:

```
h_im = findobj(gca,'Type','image');
```

In your case you may want to replace `gca` with a more explicit link to the axes you want, e.g. `handles.axes1`.  The above assumes that there is only one image in the axes.

Perhaps you meant RC as a global variable pointing to the image handle - we can't tell from the code you've given so far. My only recommendation there is to avoid using global variables if at all possible.